# What definite/indefinite article do Germans use when they don't know/forget the noun they're talking about?

Tags: noun, gender, article

Been wondering this for a while - like you're asking a question or saying something and your mind goes blank after saying "the" or "a". In German I imagine you wouldn't know which article to use before you know what noun you're saying, so do they tend to simply not use an article before they know what noun they want? Basically "forgetting" which article to use as well as the noun? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Man sagt einfach _ein/das Dingenskirchens_

Comment: Thank you I wondered if it were something like this

Comment: „Kannst Du mir aus dem Keller das Dings aus‘m Dings holen, ich muss das Dings im Bad reparieren?“ *Quote. My dad, typical request*.

Comment: ^ (Wrench, toolbox, dripping faucet.) Context is key.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *Dingenskirchens*, I suppose, is used for places (towns, villages), not generally for things. Or do you observe other practice?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I well heard that for any kind of thing, not only specific geographical places.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann It’s a regionalism, judging by my observations.

Comment: I never heard someone say "Dingenskirchens", are you from Niedersachsen? ^^ "Dings" is common here, also "Na" or "Teil"

Answer (score 17):

Very often you have a vague idea of what you want to say, and with this idea often comes some words that have similar meanings, but still are not exactly what you want to say. So you often use their genders to find an article. And when it's wrong, you just correct it when you've found the right word.

> Hast du meinen Schlüsselbund gesehen?
>   Ja, der liegt auf **dem** *<sub>(short break while thinking of: Kasten, Tisch, Schrank)</sub>* auf **der** Kommode.

If it takes longer to find the right word, you also might get something like this:

> Ja, der liegt auf dem ... na, wie heißt das? ... auf dem Dings<sup>*</sup> ... na? gibt's das? ... Ah! Der liegt auf der Kommode.

<sup>*</sup>*Dings, Dingsbums, Dingenskirchen, Zeug, Zeugs, Sachen, etc.* are words that are often used as placeholder for words that in the moment don't come up in your mind. They all just mean: "thing". (Btw: English *"thing"* and German *"Ding"* are twin-words. They mean the same and they derive from the same etymological root.)

Comment: Or short: there is no law requiring us to use the correct article for a word we do not know. We just use *some* article.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you :)

Comment: The word for words in different languages that have a shared origin is "cognate": English "thing" and German "Ding" are cognates.

Comment: ....warte, ich habs gleich...ehm....alter....mir liegts auf der zunge.....glaubst du's?.....auf der Kommode...endlich.